# Wordpress Bigwig Theme Deep Customization

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have installed bigwig theme for my WordPress site ( http://test.adamconsultingplc.com ) . The theme is pretty good, but i want to customize the features that it provides, like it has a lot of dynamic features, creating sliders, carrousels, etc. I want customization in the core functionality of theme. I don't know much about code structure of WordPress and how the theme works, But i can see that every module at the backend works like adding a post, so for adding a staff member (in STAFF MEMBERS MODULE) is just like adding a post, BUT there is no category mentioned. I want to add staff members on category based , like cities are my parent categories and under every city i have added two categories ( people and pages ). So when i add a staff member from the theme provided module , i want to add staff member in Category City->People where city is different for every staff member depending on their office location. I really need help, just to understand the structure of code of theme or just to pin point a start location , where i can start coding from.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress have its own functions set, some of them are to determine/filter categories, can't recall the function name but it is easy to find.

From there you can hack in some lines in the page you want to customize.

However if it is marely adding posts that belongs to a category, then try Ultimate-post, again not sure of the name, it is a plug in that replaces normal post list widget that allows you to filter the post by categories and much more.

also be more specific on your question, may be adding few lines of code if you've narrowed down where the problem/change is.
good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem is that i am not getting to the point where i have to edit code, i am not getting where to start from. I know in wordpress everything goes to Posts table and post_type field changes, but how custom post types displays in the admin panel , that i don't know, So, forexample, The page add_post.php(example name) has the categories listing in the right, but the custom post_type("staff") is added from add staff, but there is not categories on right, i just wanna show categories on right as the add_post.php has.

Comment: If you have the admin account and your host allow you to edit the files, go to control panel -> theme (i guess) -> editor.  There you'll find all the files, there you get a default page template and home page template, chose the one you want and you'll get the html code infront of you. Again if your host or theme provider doesn't allow you write access , you're on your own.